# how to check connection failed in json request?

Tags: json, node.js

i am working in node.js and send the json request i want to check while sending requset either server connectioned or time out if timeout then i need to show error could not establish the connection with this url.

```
request({
            url: "http://example.com/service/register/",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: spostData
        },
        function(err1,result,registerresponse){

});
```

Comment: Please, what is request? If it is coming from a module so please tell us which.

Comment: You have it right in there it's the `err1` if undefined then no error occurred, if defined then check what the error was `if(err1) console.log(err1);

Comment: the request is not in var err1 because i hit the url which is not valid then in that case web service neither response or give the error

Comment: is there any way to check connection is timeout?

Comment: you are using request module and it gives back the timeout err.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main types of timeouts: *connection timeouts* and *read timeouts*.

- A connect timeout occurs if the timeout is hit while your client is attempting to establish a connection to a remote machine.
- A read timeout occurs any time the server is too slow to send back a part of the response.

You can detect timeout errors by checking `err.code` for an '**ETIMEDOUT**' value. Further, you can detect whether the timeout was a connection timeout by checking if the `err.connect` property is set to **true**.

```
request({
            url: "http://example.com/service/register/",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            timeout: 1500,
            body: spostData
        },
        function(err,result,registerresponse){
         if(err){

          if(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'){ 

           if(err.connect === true)
              console.log('connection timeout');
           else 
              console.log('read timeout');
          }           
         }
});
```